# Last click or direct conversions vs transactions

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to compare "Last click or direct conversions" (assisted conversions) with transactions (overview) per source/medium. The numbers (except for the sums) differ widely, but in no specific way (I though conversions should be less than transactions since there can only be one per user, but often transactions are greater).

BTW: There are also more source/medium combinations in "assisted conversions" (400) than in the transactions tab (300).

Any idea what the reason is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at last click conversions, direct traffic would have more conversions than in the transaction report. Why? If for example someone visits the site via an Adwords ad and a few days later it visits the site directly and converts, the transaction is attributed to the adwords campaign. When you're looking at the assisted conversion reports it is reporting on the last click.